# Making a list of computers and their rdp settings

Tags: excel, powershell, registry

I'm trying to use Powershell to compile a simple excel spreadsheet that lists my computer's ping status's, RPD settings, and Hostnames.

I'm frustrated with the portion of the code that uses excel. I'm not really sure why, but when I run this code I'm getting an multiple errors for calling a method on a null value expression.

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content C:\Users\\Desktop\RDPSTATUS\ComputerList.txt
$excel_file_path = 'C:\Users\\Desktop\RDPSTATUS\RDPSTATUS.xlsx'


# instantiate EXCEL object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excel_file_path)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.Worksheets.item("sheet1")
$ExcelWorksheet.activate()

$row = 0
$col = 0

$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col) = "Device Name"
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col++) = "RDP Status"
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col+2) = "ping Status"

$row = 1

foreach ($computername in $ComputerList){

    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col) = $computername
    $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address = '$computername'" | Select-Object StatusCode

    If ($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0)
    {
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername )
        $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server" ,$true)
        $Value = $regkey.GetValue("fDenyTSConnections")
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col+2) = "PING"
    }
    else {
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col+2) = "NO PING"
    }

    If ($Value -eq 1){
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col++) = "RDP is Disabled"
    }

    If ($Value -eq 0){
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row , $col++) = "RDP is Enabled"
    }
}

$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.Close()
$Excel.Quit([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel))
Stop-Process -Name EXCEL -Force
```

Comment: is there a reason you are doing the ping in the excel loop? the more sensible way is to gather that info _first_ and then add it to the excel file - or, even better, simply stick with a CSV file and let the excel sheet import it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple immediate issues that I can see:

1. `$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.Worksheets.item("sheet1")` should be `$ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.item("sheet1")`. The worksheet is a property of the *workbook*, not of the Excel application.
2. `$row` and `$col` beginning values should be `1`, not `0`.
3. `$ExcelWorksheet.activate()` is not necessary.